# price.php is not being overwritten

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I am currently working on the single-product.php page and i want to change the structure of the price:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
```

When i do this, i get the price twice, one rendered with the price.php together with the changes i made and the other one without the price.php the normal WooCommerce price.

I think im missing something here, i can't do remove_action and add_action either and i want to go for a good template structure so i dont just want to go ahead and use the

```
<?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
```

in single-product.php.

Answer (score 0):

you should do this in functions.php of a child theme instead of single-product.php

Comment: Thanks, i did that but i get the price twice now